# How to use correctly nonunique in UML?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, object-diagram

Is it possible to connect a1 with b1 twice on (object diagram), while A has only one B object and it is `{nonunique}`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nonunique constraint has sense only if upper multiplicity is higher than zero (while of course you are still allowed to use it anyway). It means that in a particular association with a specific object the same object on the other side can be used more than once.

I believe that's what you wanted to achieve, however the constraint should be on the other end of the association (the one with multiplicity `*`).

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram shows just classes. Objects have an underlined name and usually do not show compartments.

The `{nonunique}` constraint in the multiplicity just tells that `B` must not be unique.

The double association between `a1` and `b1` is absolutely legal. However, without a role name it's rather pointless and a single association would be enough.